# Comment « moustiquaire » est devenu un nom féminin à la fin du 18e ?

Tags: usage, genre, origine-ou-raison, lexique

[*Moustiquaire*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moustiquaire) était d'abord un nom masculin (1768), puis un nom féminin (1798-1799) ; « Le féminin ne semble assuré qu'à la fin du 18<sup>e</sup> siècle » (TLFi).

Comment s'explique ce changement et dans quel contexte linguistique s'inscrit-il ; s'agit-il d'une normalisation de l'usage ou d'une prescription au lexique voire les deux : peut-on préciser ?

Comment: Je ne l'ai jamais entendu qu'au masculin en Belgique, cette question m'a appris que ce n'était pas le cas partout

Comment: @Eauquidort Même chose pour moi. En plus la BDL classe comme [_indûment_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3772) employé au masculin. Wiktionnaire dit Canada/Belgique. Une question pourrait suivre là-dessus.Comment on fait pour savoir que c'est un régionalisme. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu au féminin de ma vie.

Comment: @enfernette [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.ca/fr/accueil/idees-instructions/portes-et-fenetres/comment-remplacer-un-moustiquaire.html) ne semble pas pouvoir se décider ... le titre et le texte de l'article emploie le masculin tandis que la vidéo, si tu la joues, a pour titre « Comment remplacer *une* moustiquaire » !

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ouais bien ils commencent leur 2e para. par _La plupart des moustiquaire_. Note aussi la mention légale au bas _Utilisation de ce site est soumise à_. J'ai l'impression que plusieurs interventions ont été faites, incluant par un robot ou une personne qui ne parle pas français. Mais ils essayent. Dans ce contexe je rangerais peut-être leur emploi des deux genres comme du SEO afin d'attraper des requêtes basées sur des cooccurences précises avec l'un ou l'autre des genres. Enfin on peut choisir le genre avec _porte/fenêtre-moustiquaire_ mais pour l'assemblage, peut-être _treillis_ ?

Comment: @enfernette Les deux genres comme stratégies du SEO — c'est un coup de génie :) Mais réflexion faite, tu as raison : la grammaire du site n'est pas du tout fiable ...

Comment: En espagnol « moustiquaire » est indifféremment masculin (*mosquitero*) ou féminin (*mosquitera*), je pense qu'il faudrait aller chercher de ce côté-là et poser la question sur [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) pour en avoir la raison (je ne la connais pas). @jlliagre semble connaître semble connaître pas mal d'espagnol, il sait peut-être !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vu le caractère quasi contemporain des premières attestations, on peut émettre l'hypothèse que le genre du mot n'était pas bien fixé et que le masculin et le féminin ont pu être utilisés concomitamment, le féminin l'emportant dans certaines variétés de français sur le masculin, sans qu'on puisse à proprement parler de remplacement.

*Moustiquaire* est dans la deuxième moitié du 18ème un néologisme rapporté des colonies.  L'exemple du TLFi (Valm. 1768) est tiré du *Dictionnaire raisonné universel d'histoire naturelle* de Valmont de Bonare, naturaliste et voyageur français du temps.  Pour le citer :

- Mais on a une autre ressource pour la nuit, ce sont des rideaux ou un pavillon de mousseline très-claire, même de la gaze, dont le lit est environné (c'est ce qu'on nomme un *mosquiller* ou **un *moustiquaire***) : on ferme par ce moyen toute entrée aux mosquilles, sans intercepter la fraîcheur de l'air.

Mais il existe par ailleurs d'autres formes à l'époque.  Wartburg les donne dans son article *mŭsca* du FEW : moustiquière f. (1788), moustiquier m. (1829), mosquillier (1768).  A quoi s'ajoute la cousinière (1723), de même sens mais formée sur *cousin* (*cŭlex*), ancien nom du moustique qui l'a à peu près supplanté, ce d'autant plus facilement qu'il évite l'homophonie avec *cousin* (*consobrīnus*).

C'est peut-être une fausse analogie induite par la ressemblance sur le plan phonique de la finale en /ɛr/ qui a fait passer *moustiquaire* du masculin au féminin.